# How do I get all words that begin with a capital letter following a specific string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have some text that could look something like this:

```
Name is William Bob Francis Ford Coppola-Mr-Cool King-Of-The-Mountain is a fake name.
```

I would like to run a regular expression against that string and pull out

```
William Bob Francis Ford Coppola-Mr-Cool King-Of-The-Mountain
```

as a match.

My current regex looks like this:

```regex
/\b((NAME\s\s*)(((\s*\,*\s*)? *)(([A-Z\'\-])([A-Za-z\'\-]+)*\s*){2,})?)\b/ig
```

and it does most of what I want but it's not perfect. Instead of just getting the name, it is also getting the "is a" following the name like this:

```
"William Bob Francis Ford Coppola-Mr-Cool King-Of-The-Mountain is a"
```

What is a regex formula to get only the words starting with a capital letter following the "Name" label and end when the next word starts with a lowercase after a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you like `/Name ((?:[A-Z]\w+[ -]?)+)/`?

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/BFJBpZ/1

Comment: This is really close. The only thing it's missing is capturing names like O'neil or O'Leary. How do I add the check for names containing apostrophes? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: `\w` is the character class for word characters (letters, numbers, and underscore, including unicode characters that fit this category). You can create a character class with additional characters or other customizations like: `[\w']` See the [docs](https://perldoc.pl/perlrecharclass). (This is for Perl regex since that's tagged on the question, other regex engines including PCRE may have different capabiliites.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, this simple expression might work, if we always have `is` after our desired output:

```
Name is (.+?) is.+
```

#### Test

```
use strict;

my $str = 'Name is William Bob Francis Ford Coppola-Mr-Cool King-Of-The-Mountain is a fake name.
';
my $regex = qr/Name is (.+?) is.+/mp;

if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print "Whole match is ${^MATCH} and its start/end positions can be obtained via \$-[0] and \$+[0]\n";
  # print "Capture Group 1 is $1 and its start/end positions can be obtained via \$-[1] and \$+[1]\n";
  # print "Capture Group 2 is $2 ... and so on\n";
}

# ${^POSTMATCH} and ${^PREMATCH} are also available with the use of '/p'
# Named capture groups can be called via $+{name}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O9Yyq0/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Advice

[zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim) advises that:

> Perhaps, as it may not be "is", just any low-case word (so after a
>   word boundary), something like `/\b([A-Z].+?)\b[a-z.!?]/` ...
>   (probably needs tweaking, specially for the possible end of sentence
>   after the name) ?

Comment: Nice idea --- perhaps, as it may not be "_is_", just any low-case word (so after a word boundary), something like `/\b([A-Z].+?)\b[a-z.!?]/` ... (probably needs tweaking, specially for the possible end of sentence after the name) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Name\b[\sa-z]*\K(?:[A-Z][a-z]+[\s-]*)+(?=\s[a-z])
```

where

- `\K` resets the starting point of the matching after having matched `Name` followed by some words in lower case
- `(?:[A-Z][a-z]+[\s-]*)+` will match all the words starting with a capital letter
- `(?=\s[a-z])` add the constraint that the following word starts with a lower case letter

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/WBrdFU/1/

**Notes:**

> you shouldn't use the `i` option in your regex, if you do so all of
>   your char classes `[A-Z]` will at the same time match upper case
>   letters but also lower case letters... This would prevent you from
>   selecting the words that start with a capital letter!!!

**Adding the names with apostrophe**:

```
Name\b[\sa-z]*\K(?:[A-Z][a-z'\s-]*?)+(?=\s[a-z])
```

**demo**: https://regex101.com/r/WBrdFU/3/

Comment: This is not unicode sensible, imagine someone with a Ñ in his name, it will be out of the range A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I tested with regex101.com. Please check and let me know if this works for you

```
  /Name is (([\s]*[A-Z][-a-z]*)*)/
```

Group 1 has this `William Bob Francis Ford Coppola-Mr-Cool King-Of-The-Mountain`

and test it on this link below

https://regex101.com/r/M2V2in/2